# Draw mirrored arrows in PowerPoint?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, drawing

Using PowerPoint drawings I need to create two arrows, please see the sample image below. I want both arrows to have the same length and one arrow shall be the horizontal mirroring of the other arrow (so that one has an angle of e.g. 67.5° and the other one of 360° - 67.5°). Anyone can tell me how to do this? In case there are complete flowcharts or something like that in PowerPoint: Please note that I don't have a complete flow chart or something like that, I am drawing manually by adding objects like the arrows! Thanks for any hint on this!

(I am PowerPoint 2007)

[image]

Comment: Not an answer, but perhaps consider using Visio (or perhaps the open source "[Dia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dia_(software))") instead, as they are intended for (flow) charting.

Comment: the "problem" is I don't want to draw a flow chart. I have just this one case where it looks like one (for one node only!)

Comment: Ahh, gotcha.  Is exporting the arrow to a paint program and mirroring it there before importing it back into PP out of the question as well? :)

Comment: Create a copy, rotate mirror vertically and horizontally..